Fix 160144: an expected field wasn't found or couldn't be retrieved properly in ModelBuilder of ArcGIS Pro
First, I am just a starter in ArcGIS Pro, so maybe there would be some errors in my descriptions.
The problem is that when I try to run a ModelBuilder in ArcGIS Pro, I encountered an error, which is

160144: an expected field wasn't found or couldn't be retrieved properly

The geoprocessing of this is "Export Feature", and I have tried to change the input and output several times, but no effects. What is more, I am wondering if I want to fix this error, do I require to do some debugs in the codes of ArcGIS pro, or just make some changes to this process?
I have tried to change the input and output several times, but no effects.
I want to fix it and make it run properly.

Have you tried clicking on the reset field maps button?
